# How do I properly close a winforms application in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, exit

I ran the .exe for my program from the debug folder. It worked, but when I closed it, I discovered that it was still listed on the processes list in the Task Manager.

I figure I must've forgotten a step, since it's my first winforms program.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As long as the code in your `Main` method looks like this:

```
Application.Run(new MainForm());
```

Then you should be OK (assuming "MainForm" is the name of your main form). WinForms will exit the process when the form you pass in to `Application.Run` closes.

Otherwise you can call `Application.Exit()` yourself in your form's "Closed" event handler.

Comment: The Program was converted from a console application, so I managed to fix it by copying the Main method from my program.cs to my form.cs.