# Forms not closing properly if terminated due to program exit / main form close

Tags: c#

On the form called "Dev" I have the following OnFormClosing function to make sure a thread is closed properly when a user closes the form.

```
protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnFormClosing(e);
    dev.stopMultipleColorsWatcher();
}
```

Works fine if I close the "Dev" form directly. But if the "Dev" form closes because the main form ("Form1") was closed (which causes the program to exit) the `OnFormClosing()` function in "Dev" is never called, so the thread keeps on running and the program' process needs to be killed via task manager.

How do I fix this? I realise I could add an `OnFormClosing()` function to "Form1" which then calls the `OnFormClosing()` function in "Dev", but I was hoping for something a bit more clean.

**Update:**

Dev form is opened from the main form:

```
private void btn_opendev_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Dev frm = new Dev();
    frm.Show();
}
```

The main form is really called "programname.UI.Main" (I know right..) and it is opened in "Program.cs" (so the program's entry point):

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new programname.UI.Main());
}
```

Comment: Possible duplication of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414244/how-do-i-properly-close-a-winforms-application-in-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414244/how-do-i-properly-close-a-winforms-application-in-c)?

Comment: How do you open the DEV form? What is the main form of your application? which starts first?

Comment: Did you try to override OnFormClosed?

Comment: @anderhil I updated the question with that info

Comment: @user676571 Good suggestion, but unfortunately it didn't change a thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```
    Dev frm = new Dev();
    frm.Show();
```

try this

```
    Dev frm = new Dev();
    frm.Show(this);
```

This method shows an owner to a child form, and all events that go to the main form should go to the child forms.

Comment: @HansPassant The form does not run on a seperate thread... I just wanted **a** thread to be closed when the form is closed. Imagine you have a form with two buttons; one to start a thread doing something in an endless loop, and one that ends it. When a user closes the form/the program, would you not want that thread to close?