# Сlose all the already opened windows

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a menu consisting of 3 sections, each with 3 submenus. The name of one of these submenus is "exit" (it is in "help" menu, you can see in my picture).
My problem is: I open several windows, and when I apply to "exit", he must close all the already opened windows.
How can I do that? It is windows application in c#.
[image]

Comment: Please define "all windows" and specify which UI framework (WinForms, WPF) do you use.

Comment: <Dmitry> My menu bar is compiled of 3 sections (Menu, Windows, Help). Menu is complied of "Task","Tips","Exit" submenus. Windows is complied of "Vertical", "Sequence", "Close" submenus. And Help is complied of "Help tool", "About" submenus. I use C# Net (WinForms).

Comment: My questions is not about your menus, but about a set of already opened windows you are going to close. What those windows are? Do they belong to the same application instance?

Comment: I think it is duplicate of this "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414244/how-do-i-properly-close-a-winforms-application-in-c"

Comment: So just calling the Close() method on your main window doesn't work?